# `ReferenceClasses` and Imports / Depends in the DESCRIPTION

Tags: r, package, reference-class

I am developing a package containing a `ReferenceClass` that has a field of `data.table` class (defined in the `data.table` package):

```
MyRC <- setRefClass("MyRC", fields = list(myfield="data.table"))
```

When I write into package `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
Depends:
    data.table
```

everything is fine. However I heard that one should avoid using `Depends` whenever possible, so I rewrote it to:

```
Imports:
    data.table
```

This however throws an error when building the package:

```
# Error in refClassInformation(Class, contains, fields, methods, where) : 
#   class "data.table" for field 'myfield' is not defined
```

Am I really forced to use `Depends` in this case?

Comment: Are you using roxygen for documentation. It should suffice to add a #' @import data.table in the reference class documentation. This will add the appropriate entry to the NAMESPACE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include in your NAMESPACE file either

```
import(data.table)
```

to import the entire package, or import selectively

```
importClassesFrom(data.table, data.table)
```

to import just the data.table class definition. If importing selectively, it may be necessary to import other functions your package uses, e.g.,

```
importFrom(data.table, CJ)
```

Comment: This worked to build the package successfully. However, later I am calling a function in my package, which internally calls `CJ` function of `data.table`. This throws error that `CJ` is not defined, unless I explicitly call `require(data.table)`

Comment: If you are importing selectively (`importClassesFrom...`) then you'll also need to selectively import other functions your package uses. I updated my answer; it should not be necessary to say `require(data.table)`.